# C# if ExecuteScalar = null then else statement

Tags: c#, sql

Hi I am trying to do this... If the data returns back null then do something... if not do something else...

Here is the code I wrote to make this work but it isn't working??

```
        SqlConnection sqlCon1 = new SqlConnection("PRIVATE");
        SqlCommand sqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd1.CommandText = "Select AccStatus From PDMStatus WHERE Data = 'ToBeWebEnabled8'";
        sqlCmd1.Connection = sqlCon1;

        sqlCon1.Open();

        if (sqlCmd1.ExecuteScalar() == null)
        {
            Button1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Button1.Enabled = false;  
        }

        sqlCon1.Close();
```

Please help and thank you.

Comment: Can you add some details on "isn't working"? Are you getting an error or do the results differ from what you expect?

Comment: i think that sql might have a special "null" value.  I'd use the [Debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging) to check what it's actually returning when it should be null

Comment: I do not recieve any errors while compiling it just doesn't work when I test it out it runs fine but doesn't do what I want it too the button just stays disabled even though the data is NULL in SQL Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"`NULL`" as it exists in a DBMS is not represented by `null` in C# or .NET, instead the singleton value `System.DBNull.Value` is used.

You want this:

```
this.Button1.Enabled = sqlCmd1.ExecuteScalar() == DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the reader, then you can use the [`HasRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
using(var sqlCon1 = new SqlConnection("PRIVATE"))
using (var sqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand())
{
    sqlCmd1.CommandText = "Select AccStatus From PDMStatus WHERE Data = 'ToBeWebEnabled8'";
    sqlCmd1.Connection = sqlCon1;

    sqlCon1.Open();
    using (var reader = sqlCmd1.ExecuteReader())
        Button1.Enabled = reader.HasRows;
}
```

I've used the `using`-statement to ensure that everything gets dispoed/closed.

Comment: Record may exist and yet have null AccStatus value.

Comment: @Crono: good point, however, only OP knows if it can return null-values or no rows at all.

Comment: Absolutely. Just thought it was worth mentionning.